# what is the difference of creating a object of child class and upcasting

Tags: java, oop, polymorphism

What is the difference of creating child class object and upcasting?

1. `SubClass sC = new SubClass();    // instantiating object`
2. `SuperClass sC1 = new SubClass(); // Upcasting`

What is the sense of the upcasting if you can access all functions in superclass and subclass when you create a subclass object?

Comment: If the subclass has additional methods, you cannot access them with the second example (at least, not without casting).

Comment: In example 2. you are telling yourself and who reads your code that they should not care about the concrete/runtime type of `sC1` as long as they know that it is some `SuperClass`. It’s called abstraction, and it’s a key concept in programming and software development. So you’re asking a good question. And obviously one that has been asked before.